# how to set a mapRect for mkOverlay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkpolyline, mkmaprect

i want set a rect on top of the polyline route on my map.

this is what exactly i'm trying to do:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolyline *route = overlay;
        MKPolylineRenderer *routeRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:route];
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        routeRenderer.lineWidth = 5.0;
        [self.mapView.visibleMapRect = route.boundingMapRect];
        return routeRenderer;
    }
    else return nil;
}
```

i have problem with this line of code :

```
[self.mapView.visibleMapRect = route.boundingMapRect];
```

i get the "Expected identifier" error. what is wrong with this line of code? 
is that the correct way to set an Mkrect for an MKPolyline route?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you write objective-C, try this

```
self.mapView.visibleMapRect = route.boundingMapRect;
```

or

```
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:route.boundingMapRect animated:YES];
```

Comment: yes,the method work correctly, but the effect is not what i expected, it don't center the map in the center of route. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved with this tow line of code:

```
MKMapRect test = MKMapRectInset(route.boundingMapRect, -route.boundingMapRect.size.height/2, -route.boundingMapRect.size.width/2);
    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:test animated:YES];
```